# List overlapping instances of a pattern

Tags: grep

I'm trying to capture a string and the 21 characters preceding it then output this to a new file. This is what I'm using currently:

```
    grep -o ".\{21\}gt" ../data/fastadata.txt > primerdata.txt
```

And I get some of the output I desire, but it skips instances of `gt`, when any amount of the preceding 21 characters were part of a previous capture string. For example:

```
aaaatccataaatcgaggattacaagtggaaaacaaggaggcagt
```

will capture

```
tccataaatcgaggattacaagt
```

but not

```
caagtggaaaacaaggaggcagt
```

I believe it's, because the two strings would share `caagt` and the end and beginning of strings 1 & 2 respectively. It ends up missing at least half of all instances.

How do I correct this?

It captures 121 instances of `...gt`, but there are something like 200 instances of 21 characters preceding `gt` in the text file below.

Here is some text from the file I'm searching that contains instances of what I'm talking about (hard-wraps for formatting):

```
aaaccggcctcaagggaacgggtatgtctgcctcacctgtcggagatctacccaatcccagtctgcatct
aacggacactctaatgcaactgctggactgctgcttcctcaccctaacctgcagtggccaaatcgttttg
gtatccaccagcgtggagcagctattgggtcactgtcagtccgatttgtatggccagaatctactgcaga
tcacgcatcccgatgatcaggatctgttaagacagcagctaatacccagggatatagagaccctgttcta
tcagcatcagcaccaccagcagcaggggcacaatccccagcagcactccacttccacgtcggcctcaact
tcgggcagtgatctggaggaggaggaaatggagacggaggaacaccgtctgggtcggcagcagggagagg
cggacgatgacgaggatcacccgtacaaccgacgaacacccagcccgcggagaatggcccatttggcgac
cattgatgaccgactacgcatggatcggcgctgctttaccgtccgcttggctagggcttccacgcgagcg
gaggccacgcgtcattacgagcgggttaagatcgatggctgctttcgtcgcagtgactcctccttaaccg
gaggtgccgctgccaactatccgattgtctcccagctgatacgacgctcgagaaacaacaatatgctggc
tgctgctgcagcagtggcagcagaagcggcgacggtgccgccccagcacgatgccattgcccaggcggcg
ctgcacgggattagcggcaatgatattgtcctggtggccatggccagggtgctgcgagaggaacggccgc
ctgaggagacggagggtacagtgggcttgaccatttacagacagccagaaccctatcagttggagtacca
tacgaggcatctaatcgacggcagcatcatcgactgtgatcaaaggattggtctggtggcgggatatatg
aaggatgaggtgggtatattaacatcatctctctgaactgcttacgacaactaatcgtgtactctccact
cgaaacaggtgcgcaaccttagtcccttctgtttcatgcacctggacgacgttcgctgggtgattgtggc
ccttcgacaaatgtacgattgcaacagtgactacggcgagagctgctaccgtctgctgtcccgcaacggg
cgcttcatttacctgcacaccaagggatttctggaggtcgaccgtggcagtaataaggtgcattcctttc
tgtgcgtcaacacgctgctcgatgaggaggcgggccggcaaaaggtgcaggagatgaaggagaaattctc
gacaatcatcaaggcggagatgcccacgcagagcagcagtcccgatttgcccgcctcgcaggcaccgcag
caacttgagagaattgtcctctatctaatagagaacctacagaagagtgtggattcagcagagacggttg
gcggccagggcatggaaagcctaatggacgatggctacagttcgccagcaaataccttaactctcgagga
gttagctccctcgcccacgcccgccttggccttggtgccgccggctccctcatcggtcaagagctccatc
tccaagtcggtgagtgtggtcaatgtgacggcggccagaaagtttcagcaggagcatcagaagcagcgtg
aacgtgaccgtgagcagcttaaggagcgcaccaactccacgcagggcgtgatccggcaactgagcagctg
cctaagcgaggcggaaacggcatcctgtatcctatcaccagccagtagcttgagtgccagcgaagcaccg
gacacgcccgatccgcacagcaacacatcaccgccaccgtcgctccacacacgtcccagtgtcctgcatc
gaaccctgaccagcacgctgcgatgacgggctgatggaacctggtttgccttctaattgggtgtgtggaa
atggacgtcattggtagctcacgtgcccacaaacgaattagtatcggtaatataatcctggccaatcgca
aaatgaaaacccaaaatgtatcagaaaaaaacgagcattattcaaatagtttaaaaattcagccaaaaaa
cttaaaaacgaaaaaaaagagcgtgggttgaaaaaccttttgttttcatattcacatttccaagctttga
gcaatcaaacaattttaattttcagtatacacatatgtataatgagttggctttacaaaagctattaaca
aatcaagcaattgtgt
```

Comment: Actually, the issue is that it appears to simply stop matching when it reaches the first instance of `gt` (which should be fairly unsurprising). Do you have any other separations between the string and its surroundings? E.g., could you use anchors (`^` and `$`) to help delineate where the string begins and ends? It would also be helpful for you to paste (in a code block) the input file so folks here can know exactly what you're dealing with.

Comment: Could you give a more compact example, that makes a simple test case?

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that *the regex consumes the characters that it matches*. You may be able to work around that to some extent using zero-length assertions, if your regex engine supports them.

For example, if you only need to *count* the occurrences, you could use a PCRE consisting of a single character followed by a *lookahead* consisting of (21 - 1) characters followed by `gt`, e.g. in GNU grep with its PCRE mode,

```
$ printf 'aaaatccataaatcgaggattacaagtggaaaacaaggaggcagt' | 
grep -Po '.(?=.{20}gt)'
t
c
```

which outputs the initial character of each matching substring, allowing overlaps of all but a single character. (You can pipe the result to `wc -l` for an actual count).

If you need to recover the actual matching strings that is obviously harder, since you need to both consume and not consume characters - probably there is a way to do it by returning the match *indices* and then doing substring matches, for example something like this in (probably bad) perl

```
$ printf 'aaaatccataaatcgaggattacaagtggaaaacaaggaggcagt' | 
perl -lne 'while ($_ =~ m/.(?=.{20}gt)/g) {print substr($_,@+[0]-1,23)}'
tccataaatcgaggattacaagt
caagtggaaaacaaggaggcagt
```